# Get charts/graphs from Excel to Matlab Report Generator

Tags: excel, matlab, report, matlab-figure

I know most of you would advise me to just get the data with `xlsread()` and plot it in Matlab. However I still want to know if it's possible to get a chart from excel to the matlab report generator as an image (or any other format) by coding it so it's automated.

The reason is I am supposed to make a report using multiple excel files that I did not create and that contains graphs that I would like to put in my report. So that would be more convenient if I could just copy the graphs & charts into my report.

Most of the things I found were saying to plot it with Matlab and nothing else. As i understand with `xlsread` you can only get `[NUM,TXT,RAW]`. So is there a function in the Matlab Report Generator to import the Excel graphs or should I just resign myself into reploting everything?

Comment: Can matlab import png, jpeg, tiff etc?

Comment: @SolarMike What do you mean?

Comment: If you want to import the chart, then import it as an image ie those are possible image formats.

Comment: @SolarMike how can I do that in the code?

Comment: Sorry, don't run matlab, just trying to help you with a possible option. Perhaps checking the matlab help may help.

Comment: A quick google gives : https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/image.html

Comment: @SolarMike I see, well the problem is to extract the graph from the Excel Sheet. And do that by coding it in Matlab.

Comment: You clearly state "get a chart from excel to the matlab report generator as an image", so I gave you image based suggestions, **not** code based... If you ask for X then you get X...

Comment: @SolarMike sorry for this misunderstanding. I have tried to make my question a little bit clearer.

Comment: You might be able to write a VBA script to export all graphs as image files (I don’t know how, have no experience with Excel). Once you have a directory of image files, it’s easy to import them into MATLAB (many Q&A here could get you started with that).

Comment: @CrisLuengo oh yes! That could be a good solution! If I can get Matlab to run a macro that could do it (I've seen some forums about it). Thank you, I will look that up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what I wanted I followed @CrisLuengo's suggestion and wrote a VBA macro in my spreadsheet that swipes in all the workbooks I have and exports all my charts as jpg.